# Core location gives old location whenever comes from background

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have a CoreLocation manager in VC, when user pressed "get direction" button, I initalize location manager, and app opens google map direction with current location and some pre defined destination location.

Here is my problem, if app is not in background state, current location nearly always true, bu if app calling from background in same VC and user pressed again "get direction" button , current location generally shows old locations. In short, I'm troubling with multitasking and timestamp of retrieved locations did not solved my problem.

IBAction:

```
   if ( self.locationManager ) {
        [_locationManager release];
        self.locationManager = nil;
    }
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    self.locationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:LOCATION_TIMER target:self selector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocationTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Core Location Delegate:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {


NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"%f",locationAge);
if (locationAge > 3.0) 
    return;

if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) 
    return;

if ( self.currentLocation == nil || self.currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy ) {

    self.currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (self.currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy) {

        [self stopUpdatingLocations:YES];

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your example `locationAge` is a negative representation of the number of seconds since the `timestamp` of `newLocation`. This means that `locationAge` will never be greater than 3 and you're effectively letting every update through the sieve.

Set `locationAge` like this:

```
NSTimeInterval locationAge = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

Comment: Mark, I see it in apple's LocateMe sample code, I copied: NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (locationAge > 5.0) return; Then, we say that is it wrong ?

Comment: Oh right they're using `-timeIntervalSinceNow` so it's going to be a negative value which is then reversed by the additional negative. (That seems completely ass backwards to me) How do you know that you're getting old updates? Are you sure that they're more than 3 seconds old?

Comment: I'm 100% sure, because, I tested with the car, first I opened app and get direction for some pre-defined venue which is correct then I traveled appromixately 2-2.5 km, then I launch app again ( from background state ) and it gives me wrong location which is old one. I have tested 3-4 times like this, and all are wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that you're just seeing the last location before the app resigned and the new locations aren't meeting any of your accuracy requirements right away? You are checking for the best accuracy...

Comment: But I use also NSTimer to stop update, even new locations are not meeting with accuracy requirements, I assigned it currentLocation variable as you see in code snippet, I will expect little changes in coordinate values at least, but I'm very unlucky.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter same problem,

Also, some tutorials related with core location on web, lead me this problem.

Of course, I keep CLLocation ivar in my VC, whenever CLLocation ivar
sets and google maps called, my app goes to background.

Then, my app calls from background by user, and start updating locations,
and old CLLocation ivar is not nil and probably best horizantal accuracy then
newly comes. Therefore;

```
if ( self.currentLocation == nil || self.currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy )
```

this line cause problems, and old location in CLLocation ivar
never replaced.

So I changed viewDidDisappear like this and I assigned nil value to CLLocation variable and works perfectly.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; // CLLocationManager
    self.locationManager = nil; 
    [self.locationTimer invalidate]; // NSTimer
    self.locationTimer = nil;
    self.currentLocation = nil; // CLLocation 
}
```

p.s : thank you Mark Adams